# Entry command for pre-commit built-in hooks

Tags: python, git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I would like to run some of the built-in hooks available from the [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) package from the command line, not as hooks but just from the command line to spot clean files as necessary.

For example, if I want to run black on an arbitrary file in my project, I can just run it with `black [directory]` command.

I don't see in the documentation what the entry commands for built-in hooks such as `trailing-whitespace` are.

For example, I would like to clean up trailing whitespace in `foo.py` by just typing `trailing-whitespace foo.py`. This does not work, however.

How would one go about doing this?

As a side note, this should also be possible if running hooks as `local` with pre-commit installed in a local env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which repository you're installing you'd need to `pip` install that externally and then run the command.  **You probably don't want to do that since that defeats the purpose of the framework** (it manages the installs for you so you don't have to).  You probably want to `pre-commit run trailing-whitespace --files ...` instead

that said, you still can if you want.  For the trailing-whitespace hook [you mention](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks#trailing-whitespace) -- that comes from `pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks`.  If you look at [the alternate installation instructions](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks#as-a-standalone-package), you can `pip install pre-commit-hooks` and then run the executable for that (you can find the exact executable name from the `entry` field in the repository manifest, in that case: [`entry: trailing-whitespace-fixer`](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks/blob/11a2fdbab88e927af4d64e28a238df0f3b8693d1/.pre-commit-hooks.yaml#L204))

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit and pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks